# How to enable screen saver on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, screensaver

How do I enable screensaver mode on a Mac programmatically using objective-c/cocoa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple one-liner with `NSWorkspace`. All we need to do is open the ScreenSaverEngine.

Here it is in Swift:

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app")!)
```

Here it is in Objective-C:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app"]];
```